# Opentelemetry Bridge API for Java

Tags: open-telemetry

We have an existing application which emits log using slf4j. We are looking to onboard our application on opentelemetry. We are following the data model for opentelemetry and below is the json format we would need. Is there a way to structure application log in the json format and send log to opentelemetry without changing the application ?

```json
{"timestamp": "22023-01-11T14:46:25.910Z",
"spanId": "3e7a9e94-205e-4347-8e1f-9ada36f9c766",
"traceId": "2F41F2F9-8237-472A-990B-48ACF8CF6DA6",
"severityText": "Error",
"body": {
    "Status": "400"
    },
"resource": {
    "attributes": [{
        "key": "apiName",
        "value": {
            "stringValue": "testAPI"
            }
        }]
    }
"attributes": [{
    "key": "byteSent",
        "value": {
            "intValue": "256"
        }
    }]
}
```

I am looking for a sample code

Comment: I need a formatter which will populate the json with all values related to timestamp, spanId etc and pickup the body from the log message supplied by application.